# upload video from iphone device to server in php

Tags: php, video

I am working on the project which includes uploading image and video of user from iphone device. I am handling the backend with PHP. For uploading images I am getting the base64encode string and I have use following code to upload the image -

```
$str = $data['pictureurl'];  // base64encode string 

$newVar = base64_decode($str);

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'userimages/');

$img = $str;
$date = strtotime(date("m-d-y H:i:s"));

$img = str_replace('data1:image/png;base64,', '', $img);

$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

$data1 = base64_decode($img);

$file = UPLOAD_DIR . strtolower($data['firstName']).strtolower($data['lastName']). "_".$userId . '.png';

$totalpath = $path.$file;

@chmod('userimages/', 0777);
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data1);
```

From this code, image gets uploaded to the server in specified directory properly with .png extension. May I use the same code for uploading video making the file type .flv or .mov? I have tried it, but file gets placed in the folder with 0 bytes of data. What could be the problem?  or is there any another solution to upload such file ?

Comment: Have you checked for error codes or anything the likes? Maybe the movie file is too large for PHP to accept?

Comment: movie file is not too large, it is 4mb file. Is there any another way to upload file?

Comment: Yeah, but have you checked in your php.ini, if 4 MB isn't already 'too large'?

Comment: no, there is limit of 20M in php.ini

Comment: Could the issue possibly be that str_replace up there?